# In Atom, how do I style the line that shows in between tabs when a tab is grabbed?

Tags: css, electron, atom-editor

I am having the hardest time trying to figure out how to style that line.

I know that the class is called `is-drop-target` but I can't scroll through the list of styles to figure out what styles are applied to which properties because the cursor is holding the tab for the class to show and scrolling is not allowed when the cursor is holding something.

I've tried properties `background-color`, `border-color` and `color` but none of them worked.

I've tried pseudo-elements `::before` and `::after` but neither of those worked either.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

**EDIT:** 
I am using `UI Theme` named `seti-ui`. https://atom.io/themes/seti-ui

[image: Screenshot of the line that shows in between the tabs when a tab is grabbed]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The class name for the line when dragging tabs around is named `placeholder`. Try the code below to see what I mean.

```
.placeholder {
  background-color: yellow !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest to debug this is by using the element inspector and manually adding a list-item with the class `.placeholder` between two tabs.

*Example:*

```
<li is="tabs-tab" class="texteditor tab sortable modified active" data-type="TextEditor">...</li>
<li class="placeholder"></li>
<li is="tabs-tab" class="texteditor tab sortable modified" data-type="TextEditor">...</li>
```

You can then expand the placeholder item and modify the `:before`/`:after` pseudo elements.

Here is an example for the *Atom Dark* theme:

[image]

```
.tab-bar .placeholder:before {
    z-index: 1;
    margin: 0;
    width: 2px;
    height: 2.5em;
    background-color: #519fee;
}

.tab-bar .placeholder:after {
    z-index: 0;
    top: 1.25em;
    margin: -4px 0 0 -3px;
    border-radius: 0;
    border: 4px solid #519fee;
    transform: rotate(45deg);
    background: transparent;
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

I am using Atom version 1.14.4. I have checked developer tools in the version I have there is a class `tab-bar` applied on `ul`. List elements of this `ul` has property `background`. You can change it.

[image: atom]

Comment: It doesn't do anything for me. Sorry, let me edit the question and mention that I am using `UI Theme` called `seti-ui`. https://atom.io/themes/seti-ui